# ajax errors on my asp.net site

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, flexigrid

I've developed an asp.net site.in most pages of it , I use the `$.ajax method` of `jquery` library in cliend site , and web method in server side.

When I run my site on local computer , is goes right , but when I upload it on my host , most of ajax request for goes with error.

**This is an example :**

EX : I've a flexi grid and want to load data into it when is document ready , but and error uccurred and i catch it by firebug :

```
The method 'FetchCountryList' returns a value of type 'System.Xml.XmlDocument', which
cannot be serialized as Xml. Original error: Unable to generate a temporary class 
(result=1). error CS2001: Source file 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\d2h0eyni.0.cs' could not be 
found error CS2008: No inputs specified
```

I want help to solve this error

This is my code in client side :

```
               $("#GrdCountry").flexigrid({
                    url: 'CountryDefinition.aspx/FetchCountryList',
                    dataType: 'xml',
                    colModel: [
                        { display: 'Name', name: 'Name', width: 210, sortable: true, align: 'left' },
                        { display: 'Code', name: 'Code', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'left' },
                        { display: 'Capital', name: 'Capital', width: 210, sortable: true, align: 'left' },
                        { display: 'Actions', width: 100, align: 'Center'}],
                    buttons: [
                        { name: 'Add', bclass: 'add', onpress: addOpr },
                        { separator: true}],
                    searchitems: [
                        { display: 'Name', name: 'Name', isdefault: true },
                        { display: 'Capital', name: 'Capital'}],
                    sortname: "Name",
                    sortorder: "asc",
                    usepager: true,
                    //title: 'Countries',
                    useRp: true,
                    rp: 10,
                    resizable: false,
                    showTableToggleBtn: false,
                    width: 783,
                    height: 330
                });
```

and this is my code in server side :

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
    public static XmlDocument FetchCountryList(int page, int rp, string sortname, string sortorder, string query, string qtype)
    {
        CountryBL CountryBLO = new CountryBL();
        XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),

                new XElement("rows",
                    new XElement("page", page.ToString()),
                    new XElement("total", CountryBLO.Load().Count.ToString()),
                    CountryBLO.Load(page, rp, sortname, sortorder, query, qtype).Select(row => new XElement("row", new XAttribute("Id", row.Id.ToString()),
                                                      new XElement("cell", row.Name.ToString()),
                                                      new XElement("cell", row.Code.ToString()),
                                                      new XElement("cell", row.Capital.ToString()),
                                                      new XElement("cell", "<img id='imgEdit' lang='" + row.Id.ToString() + @"' style='cursor:pointer;border:0px;' src='../../Storage/Images/FlexGrid/edit.png' />
                                                                            <img id='imgDelete' lang='" + row.Id.ToString() + "' style='cursor:pointer;border:0px;' src='../../Storage/Images/FlexGrid/delete.gif' />")                        
                                                    )
                                )
                    )
        );
        return Tools.XDocumentToXmlDocument(xmlDoc);
    }
```

Thanks , Ali

Comment: how can assign bounty for my question!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try returning into a String.

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
    public static String FetchCountryList(int page, int rp, string sortname, string sortorder, string query, string qtype)
    {
        CountryBL CountryBLO = new CountryBL();
        XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),

                new XElement("rows",
                    new XElement("page", page.ToString()),
                    new XElement("total", CountryBLO.Load().Count.ToString()),
                    CountryBLO.Load(page, rp, sortname, sortorder, query, qtype).Select(row => new XElement("row", new XAttribute("Id", row.Id.ToString()),
                                                      new XElement("cell", row.Name.ToString()),
                                                      new XElement("cell", row.Code.ToString()),
                                                      new XElement("cell", row.Capital.ToString()),
                                                      new XElement("cell", "<img id='imgEdit' lang='" + row.Id.ToString() + @"' style='cursor:pointer;border:0px;' src='../../Storage/Images/FlexGrid/edit.png' />
                                                                            <img id='imgDelete' lang='" + row.Id.ToString() + "' style='cursor:pointer;border:0px;' src='../../Storage/Images/FlexGrid/delete.gif' />")                        
                                                    )
                                )
                    )
        );

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        using (TextWriter writer = new StringWriter(builder))
        {
            doc.Save(writer);
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: i am publishing it,i work on local computer,wait to check it after i uploaded it.

Comment: ah,it did not work, steel that error occurred,want to check my site yourself?and see what happen?

Comment: 1 min,i think it work (sorry i had make a mistake) i am checking it again,

Comment: WOW it works :O (sorry i had make a mistake,you idea work great)
THAT WAS GREAT .thank you so much
this link is goes correct with your idea : 
http://datagts.net/cpanel/CountryDefinition.aspx
an this link has error 
http://datagts.net/cpanel/RegionDefinition.aspx

Comment: thanks again,i will change all my page with your great idea,thanks again.i am so happy